# Use different keys for changing layouts

Tags: 16.04, unity, gnome, 18.04, mate

How to change keyboard layouts using different keys/combinations?

Default is `Alt + Shift L`. It cycles between 2 layouts.

How can I add `Shift R` key to switch to my first `EN` layout?

Comment: What's your Ubuntu version and flavour (Unity/GNOME/KDE/MATE etc.)?

Comment: @pomsky, In tags. Now I use 18.04 Mate and 16.04 Unity, but I can switch to 18.04 gnome.